# Why does forcing to reload the page and controller work with an additional slash using $location.path() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When using `$location.path()` in AngularJS and passing the same URL as the current URL you are, why

```
$location.path('/currentURL');
```

doesn't reload the page and controller, but

```
$location.path('/currentURL/');
```

with an additional slash in the end of the URL does it? What happens, that you can force the reloading with just an additional slash?

Comment: Because `/currentURL/` is a different url indeed. `'/currentURL/' !== '/currentURL'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upto my knowledge, when you dont put / forward-slash at end, angularjs app will treat it as same url and it wont load page, but when you put forward-slash angularjs app will treat it as differnet url and will reload page.